# Array Of Objects with data of exams submitted, how can I get the average grade of each student in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an array of objects that contain information about all the exams submitted during a period of time. It's structure's like this:

```
[
    { name: 'Freddy', grade: 10, date: '20/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Jose', grade: 8, date:'20/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Freddy, grade: 8', date: '25/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Daniel', grade: 5, date: '21/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Jose', grade: 5 }, date: '22/07/22',
  ]
```

What I need is to ignore the date value and just calculate the average grade of each student and get a simple array like this:

```
[9, 6.5, 5]
```

Now let's say I want the array to follow a specific order so how can I rearrange it following this order: Freddy -> Jose -> Daniel ?

It seems kind of weird but I kind of need the output to be like this in order to use it as a dataset for Chart.js later on.

Answer (score 2):

To do this:

- I used `reduce` to create a dictionary that has each student's grade sum and grade count.

  - I used a dictionary because it makes it easy to search through it while `reduce` iterates through the array.
- Then I used `Object.keys()` to get an array of the dictionarie's keys and `map`-ed that array into an array that has an object for each student's average grade.

  - I did it this way because I assumed that this output could be useful. It would have been simpler to loop over the dictionary and convert it to a dictionary of averages.
- Then we `map` the array of objects to just the averages.

```js
const students = [
  { name: 'Freddy', grade: 10, date: '20/07/2022' },
  { name: 'Jose', grade: 8, date:'20/07/2022' },
  { name: 'Freddy', grade: 8, date: '25/07/2022' },
  { name: 'Daniel', grade: 5, date: '21/07/2022' },
  { name: 'Jose', grade: 5 , date: '22/07/22'}
]

const grouped = students.reduce(
  (output, student) => {
    const name = student.name
    if (output[name]) {
      output[name].gradeTotal += student.grade;
      output[name].count += 1;
    }
    else {
      output[name] = {
        gradeTotal: student.grade,
        count: 1
      }
    }
   return output
  }, {})

console.log('Grouped by student: ', grouped)

const studentAverages = Object.keys(grouped).map(name => (
   {
    name,
    average: grouped[name].gradeTotal / grouped[name].count 
   }
  )
)

console.log('Student averages: ', studentAverages)

const justAverages = studentAverages.map(student => student.average)

console.log('Just averages:', justAverages)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want.

1. I made some variables for `sum`, `counter` to count the occurrence of each name, `average` and `avgArr` to store the averages
2. Then made nested loops. The outer loop to take each object name and store it in the `name` variable. The inner loop loop through the array, search for the name and calculate the `average` for each person. Then add this `average` to the `avgArr` array.
3. I added `checked` property to each object to avoid taking the same object more than one time if it's `true` skip that object, if the object doesn't have this property take this object, add the `checked` property and set it to `true`. If you don't want this property you can remove it later.

```js
let arr =[
    { name: 'Freddy', grade: 10, date: '20/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Jose', grade: 8, date:'20/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Freddy', grade: 8, date: '25/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Daniel', grade: 5, date: '21/07/2022' },
    { name: 'Jose', grade: 5 , date: '22/07/22' }];
    let sum = 0;
    let counter = 0;
    let avg;
    const avgArr = [];
    for (const i of arr){
      let name = i.name;
      if (i.checked === true) {
        continue;
      }
      for (const j of arr){
        if (name === j.name) {
          j.checked = true;
          sum += j.grade;
          counter +=1;
        }
      }
      avg = sum / counter;                                                        
      avgArr.push(avg);
      sum = counter = 0;    
    }
     console.log(avgArr); // [9, 6.5, 5]
```